# What is the highest number of spells that can be cast in one round?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic, time

I'm aware of the hotly debated "...normal limit of one spell per round" text from the rules on magic casting time. Assuming that this doesn't mean anything substantial, however, what is a theoretical ceiling on the number of spells one can cast or directly cause to be cast in a single round? I'm only concerned with spells per round from the perspective of the caster, not apparent time, so *time stop* doesn't count. I'm willing to consider any combination of other spells, magic items, class abilities, etc.

Comment: "From the perspective of the caster" and "apparent time" are the same thing. I think you meant "not absolute time" or something to that effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Four (Base rules)

## Five (Including hero point rules)

## Ten (Or unlimited) (Including hero point and mythic rules)

(In one round)

You can:

1. Cast a spell via a standard action
2. Cast a spell via a swift action ([Quicken spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic---final) et al.)
3. Cast/activate a spell from a [contingency](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contingency)
4. As a magus use your offhand to attack with a weapon and activate a [spell storing weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-storing) to cast another spell, since you can use [Spell Combat](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-) to cast one spell and attack at the same time.
5. Cast a spell by expending a [hero point](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/hero-points).

If you are using [Mythic Tiers](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/mythicAdventures/mythicHeroes.html) then you can cast/trigger ***Six*** spells on yourself with contingency, this is because Mythic contingency allows you to activate 1 contingency spell (on yourself) plus half your mythic tier. Maximum mythic Tier is 10. So you can use mythic contingency to activate 6 spells at once, plus the others.

Or you can activate/cast a theoretically unlimited number of contingency spells as the range of the spell with Mythic increases to touch, allowing you to place contingency on any person you touch.

Ie if Wizard Bob spends a year using Mythic Contingency casting [Beast Shape](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape) on all his minons which is activated when he shouts "By the power of Greyskull" then his entire army can be turned into battle cats if they're in earshot of him.

**Bonus extra pointless spell!**

Other wackiness is the use of [Heroic Finale](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/spells/heroicFinale.html) which allows:

> With a flourish, you immediately end the performance, and one creature
>   within range affected by your bardic performance can make a move
>   action or a standard action of their choice.

Since you can yourself be the subject of your own performance you can theoretically use it on yourself but it's pretty pointless as you're spending a standard action to get another standard action - but it is another spell!

I'm discounting someone else casting this on the character as it activates on their turn and it's only the caster using it.

You could also argue that you could chain-cast Heroic Finale on yourself to cast as many spells as you have 4th level (and above) slots (as long as they're Heroic Finale!) but since the spell states "you immediately end the performance" you'd only get one spell out of it in my book as the bardic performance has ended.

Comment: You can also cast an immediate action spell along the swift action one, as it only bars you from using your swift action on your *next* turn.

Comment: I did consider that; but the text for immediate action: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#immediateActions says "Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift action, and counts as your swift action for that turn." If we start moving into an entire round situation rather than the characters go, then you could fire your spells and then an immediate action directly after your go, but that's sort of moving into a new turn... (I think!)

Comment: It's kind of hair-splitting, but you are right that the immediate action spell would not technically be in the same turn.

Comment: Would it be possible to get two spells for every standard action by using the magus's spellstrike with a spell storing weapon?

Comment: Nice one; yes that'd work as well; that's another spell; I'll add that in :)

Comment: Spellstrike just means you use a weapon attack instead of a touch attack for a spell, it doesn't mean you cast a spell while attacking. It's not technically an action, it just changes the free touch attack of a spell to a weapon attack, so any class could fit in #4 using a spell-storing weapon.

Comment: Good catch; that should be Spell Combat! Which significantly allows you as a full round action to attack with your weapon in your off hand and cast a spell with your other hand.

Answer (score 1):

### Using the optional [Hero Point](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/hero-points) rules, you are able to cast 3 spells per round.

- 1 Spell with a Swift or Immediate action casting time such as [Stone Shield](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/stone-shield) or via the [Quicken Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/quicken-spell-metamagic---final) Metamagic Feat
- 1 Spell via a Standard Action
- 1 Spell via a Hero Point Standard Action.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what spells you are trying to cast. Some spells have an extended casting time that can last for several rounds(such as the Masterwork Spell[can't remember the real name]). However there are both normal spells(like Burning Hands) and quick spells (such as Cheetah Sprint). Since you have 1 movement action, 1 standard action, 1 quick/swift action and infinite free actions(like quick draw), you could cast an unadjusted amount of 2 spells. For instance, you could *TECHNICALLY* cast Cheetah Sprint on yourself, run across a map  while quickdrawing and dropping individual caltrops, and heal someone near the end of your run (if there was such a thing as spellcasting at the end of a charge/run)

Comment: Hey, welcome to the site!  Thanks for trying to help out - I'd forgotten that some spells are naturally a Swift action such as Cheetah's Sprint.  Why don't you stop by and read the [Tour] or say hi in the [Chat] when you have a chance?

With your answer - while you are correct that you can cast Cheetah's Sprint and run or charge in the same round, you aren't able to cast a spell while running or charging.