# Ways to cast multiples buff spells in one round

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

I discovered in this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/75877/23750) the Quiescent weaving ability (for War Weaver, a Prestige Class in D&D3.5), which allows to store multiple pre-casted spells, ready to be released with only a move action.

My lvl 9 Magus often spend a few round before combat to buff herself and/or her allies with multiples buff spells (generally Shield, Defensive Shock and Cat's Grace). It's usually not a problem as those spells last long enough to be cast a few minutes in advance, but in case of an ambush (or any other unplanned attack), it takes several rounds for her to reach her full potential.

**Is there a way in Pathfinder to cast multiples buff spells in one round?**

I'm looking specifically for something my Magus could do, but I'm also interested in other ways.

Comment: Related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69697/what-is-the-highest-number-of-spells-that-can-be-cast-in-one-round/69711#69711

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For something directly equivalent to casting a buff spell and activating it as a move action I don't think is in the game but there are many means of getting spells out.

### [Accelerated Drinker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/combat-traits/accelerated-drinker) for Potions (trait)

This allows you to drink a potion as a move action, especially good as spells that can take up to 1 minute to cast take effect instantaneously when imbibed. Enlarge Person therefore can take effect by the move action of the target rather than a full round action otherwise. Many Level 1 buffing spells have a duration of 1 minute per level so even a cheap CL1 potion will last long enough. It can get exponentially more expensive with higher level spells.

### [Spell Storing weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/spell-storing) (Magical quality of Weapon)

For weapons, these are generally most useful with offensive attacks though nothing says they must be offensive spells. For example a small dagger of spell storing does pitiful damage but may cast any level 1-3 spell into the target which could be a buffing spell for an ally. So you can get multiple spells cast in one round by effectively getting the target to cast it on themselves.

### [Spell Storing armour](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/magic-armor-and-shield-special-abilities/spell-storing) (Magical quality of Armour)

This is similar to a spell storing weapon except it doesn't have any limit on casting time. So if Adam make an unarmed strike on his friend Bob who is wearing spell storing armour loaded with Magic Circle Against Evil, Adam has such a spells cast on them. It just has to be limited to a touch spell.

### Swift action Spells

So many spells are overlooked as the overwhelming majority of spells are a standard action or more to cast, yet there are a few exceptions, [Dazzling Blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dazzling-blade) is a first level spell that is only a swift action to cast yet gives the ability to blind. An excellent first level buffing spell giving anyone with a weapon the capability to get out a devastating de-buff. This swift action cast can be combined with a Standard Action casting spell.

### Multi Target spells

Similar to being able to get spells out quicker with a Swift Action, having a standard action go further by simultaneously buffing multiple allies eases the burden, a very popular one is [Haste](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/haste) as it targets 1 creature per level.

### [Symbol of Mirroring](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/symbol-of-mirroring) (pre-casting of spell)

This is a level 3 spell with a long casting time but the result is permanent. The way the spell is worded your party can gain the benefit of this buff simply by the item being available for all the party to touch. A very handy buff giving a 50% miss chance. This allows the effect of casting a spell by allies only investing a melee touch attack on the Symbol. You could configure the symbol to be activated by looking at it when uncovered but then enemies could benefit from it too.

*General tactics:*

Going Invisible can be a worthy investment if you are committed to getting out those buff spells, the spell doesn't end unless you take direct offensive action. Though what may be necessary is investing in zoning spells which delay the enemy from attacking either you or allies, this can be as direct as [Web](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/web) which delays most enemies a long time, or even something like [Obscuring Mist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/o/obscuring-mist), you and your allies are effectively immune inside the mist and if close together you can still see each other well enough to cast buffing spells.

Many buffing spells are so situational for allies they may want to consider the [Sipping Jacket](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/jacket-sipping) that means they can use only 1 round of a potion's duration at a time, useful for a Rogue who may occasionally need to go invisible for when their normal means of stealth otherwise fall short.

Also, if you like to use lots of pre-battle buffs, consider scrolls of [Channel the Gift](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/channel-the-gift) which means if you cast a level 1-3 spell in the next round then a spell slot isn't used up.

Comment: Do I have to stab myself to activate spell storing weapon/armor, or would a simple slap on the chest with the pommel be enough?

Comment: @Luris Quoting spell storing weapon on the condition to allow a cast: "Anytime the weapon strikes a creature and the creature takes damage from it" and it so it has to do SOME damage. A slap from a pommel would not be enough. The rules don't actually say how hitting yourself for minimum damage works, GM has to rule with common sense. Spell storing armour is half the price and much clearer how it works.

Comment: You could stab yourself with nonlethal damage though (-4 to hit).